# Symfony2 Session - Proper Start and Retrieval

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm using Symfony2 to talk to an API then start a session. I have my `OauthCallbackController.php` that finishes the authorization process then starts a sessions and sets some variables. I then want to be able to access those variables from my other controllers, to ensure that I have proper access to the API.

There are so many different (and confusing) ways I've read about in Symfony2 sessions, right now I'm using below:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class OauthCallbackController extends Controller
{
public function callbackAction(Request $request)
{

    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();


    // Oauth Code here
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $access_token = $response['access_token'];
    $instance_url = $response['instance_url'];


    $session->set('access_token', $access_token);
    $session->set('instance_url', $instance_url);

    return new RedirectResponse("rootpage.com");

}
}
```

This is how I perceive starting a session, but I cannot figure out how to use/access this session in my other controllers. So if anyone can help me with that, or if I'm doing the session creation wrong, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need start yourself a session (Symfony does that for you), nor you need to create your own `Session` object.

In your controllers you can get the session object that Symfony provides from the `Request` object.

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

That's all. You can read the documentation about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session).

Comment: Currently, some of my controllers have different actions, such as `public function idAction($id)`. Do I need to create another function so that I can have the `(Request $request)` parameters?

Comment: No, just do `idAction($id, Request $request)` or `idAction(Request $request, $id)`, whatever, are fine both

Comment: Will I need to change anything in routing for this? I wouldn't want the url path to be impacted. For example website.com/1234 would pass into that event controller, but if the `idAction($id, Request $request)`, would it still work properly?

Comment: No, you don't need to change anything. Symfony uses Reflection to inject the most appropriate argument. You can see how it works [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L102).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, @Federico, so much for this information, this has helped a lot! So I'll just add in that parameter to any controller that needs to access session variables.